# Bidirectional path tracing

Tags: rendering, raytracing

I'm making a bidirectional path tracer and I have some troubles.

To be clear :
    1) One point light
    2) All objects are diffuse
    3) All objects are spheres, even walls (they are very large)
    4) NO MIS WEIGHTING

The light emission is a 3D vector. The BRDF of a sphere is a 3D vector. Hard coded.

In the main function below I generate EyePath and LightPath then I connect them. At least I try.

In this post I will talking about the main function then EyePath then LightPath. The talking about connecting function will appear once EyePath and Light are good.

1. First questions :

   - Does the generation of the first light point is good ?
   - Do I need to compute this point according to the emission of the light source? or is it just the emission ? The line is commented where i'm filling the Vertices structure.
   - Do I need to translate fromlight ? In order to put it on the sphere

The code below is sampled in the main function. Above it there is two for loops going through all pixels. Camera.o is the eye. CameraRayDir is the direction to the current pixel.

`//The path light starting point is at the same position as the light
Ray fromLight(Vec(0, 24.3, 0), Vec());
Sphere light = spheres[7];`

```
#define PDF 0.15915494309 // 1 / (2 * PI)    

for(int i = 0; i < samps; ++i)
{
    std::vector<Vertices> PathEye;
    std::vector<Vertices> PathLight;

    Vec cameraRayDir = cx * (double(x) / w - .5) + cy * (double(y) / h - .5) + camera.d;

    Ray rayEye(camera.o, cameraRayDir.norm());              

    // Hemisphere oriented towards the top
    fromLight.d = generateRayInHemisphere(fromLight.o,Vec(0,1,0)).d;

    double f = clamp(n.dot(fromLight.d.norm()));

    Vertices vert;
    vert.d = fromLight.d;           
    vert.x = fromLight.o;
    vert.id = 7;
    vert.cos = f;
    vert.n = Vec(0,1,0).norm();

    // this one ?
    //vert.couleur = spheres[7].e * f / PDF;

    // Or this one ?
    vert.couleur = spheres[7].e;

    PathLight.push_back(vert);

    int sizeEye = generateEyePath(PathEye, rayEye, maxDepth);
    int sizeLight = generateLightPath(PathLight, fromLight, maxDepth);

    for (int s = 0; s < sizeLight; ++s)
    {
        for (int t = 1; t < sizeEye; ++t)
        {
          int depth = t + s - 1;
          if ((s == 0 && t == 0) || depth < 0 || depth > maxDepth)
            continue;

          pixelValue = pixelValue + connectPaths(PathEye, PathLight, s, t);
        }
     }
}
```

For the EyePath I intersect the geometry then I compute the illumination according to the distance with the light. The colour is black if the point is in the shadow.

Second question : For the eye path and the direct illumination, is the computation good ? I've seen in many code, people use the pdf even in direct illumination. But I'm only using point light and spheres.

```
int generateEyePath(std::vector<Vertices>& v, Ray eye, int maxDepth)
{
  double t;
  int id = 0;

  Vertices vert;

  int RussianRoulette;

  while(v.size() <= maxDepth)
  {

    if(distribRREye(generatorRREye) < 10)
      break;

    // Intersect all the geometry
    // id is the id of the intersected geometry in an array
    intersect(eye, t, id);

    const Sphere& obj = spheres[id];

    // Intersection point
    Vec x = eye.o + eye.d * t;

    // normal
    Vec n = (x - obj.p).norm();  

    Vec direction = light.p - x;   

    // Shadow ray
    Ray RaytoLight = Ray(x, direction.norm());        

    const float distance = direction.length();

    // shadow
    const bool visibility = intersect(RaytoLight, t, id);

    const Sphere &lumiere = spheres[id];

    float degree = clamp(n.dot((lumiere.p - x).norm()));

    // If the intersected geometry is not a light, then in shadow
    if(lumiere.e.x == 0)
    {
      vert.couleur = Vec(); 
    }
    else // else we compute the colour
       // obj.c is the brdf, lumiere.e is the emission
       vert.couleur = (obj.c).mult(lumiere.e / (distance * distance)) * degree;    

    vert.x = x;
    vert.id = id;
    vert.n = n;
    vert.d = eye.d.normn();
    vert.cos = degree;

    v.push_back(vert);

    eye = generateRayInHemisphere(x,n);
  }

  return v.size();
 }
```

For the LightPath, for a given point, I compute it according to the previous one and the values at this point. Like in a common path tracing.\n

Third question: Is the colour computation good ?

```
int generateLightPath(std::vector<Vertices>& v, Ray fromLight, int maxDepth)
{
   double t;
   int id = 0;

   Vertices vert;

   Vec previous;

   while(v.size() <= maxDepth)
   {
    if(distribRRLight(generatorRRLight) < 10)
      break;

    previous = v.back().couleur;

    intersect(fromLight, t, id);

    // intersected geometry
    const Sphere& obj = spheres[id];

    // Intersection point
    Vec x = fromLight.o + fromLight.d * t;

    // normal
    Vec n = (x - obj.p).norm();   

    double f = clamp(n.dot(fromLight.d.norm()));

    // obj.c is the brdf
    vert.couleur = previous.mult(((obj.c / M_PI) * f) / PDF);  

    vert.x = x;
    vert.id = id;
    vert.n = n;
    vert.d = fromLight.d.norm();
    vert.cos = f;

    v.push_back(vert);

    fromLight = generateRayInHemisphere(x,n);
  }

  return v.size();
 }
```

For the moment I get this result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0esy.jpg)

The connecting function will come once EyePath and LightPath are good.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Try the spherical reference scene mentioned in this paper. I think then you can work out most of your questions by yourself since it has an analytical solution.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221546261_Testing_Monte-Carlo_Global_Illumination_Methods_with_Analytically_Computable_Scenes

It would save your time to implement and verify your understanding with path tracing and light tracing first, then try to combine them with weights.